# Get excel column into a variable

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to move some xls data into json. I can't just use a ready solution, since this is a bit of a special case.

Here's the excel
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pandas

xl = pandas.ExcelFile("./data/file.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("2")
x = df["XX"][0]
print(x)

# writing to file
text_file = open("json_files/Output.json", "w")

# text_file.write(json_str)

text_file.close()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\Capgemini\Excel_to_Json\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'XX'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excelToJson.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = df["XX"][0]
  File "C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\Capgemini\Excel_to_Json\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\Capgemini\Excel_to_Json\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'XX'
```

It seems to not be able to find the column name.

I'm using this [video](https://youtu.be/xfrHZgMKllM?t=74) as reference

```
import pandas

xl = pandas.ExcelFile("file.xlsx")
# df = xl.parse("Text")
# print(df.columns)
# # x = df["XX"][0]
# # print(x)

df = pandas.Dataframe(xl)
print(df.columns)
# if you can see the columns
print(df["XX"])
# if this is success
dictionary = {"XX": list(df["XX"])}

# writing to file
text_file = open("json_files/Output.json", "w")

# text_file.write(json_str)

text_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you show us what `df.columns` looks like and other details of the dataframe?

Comment: `df.columns` is equal to `Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4'], dtype='object')`. Why is that?

Comment: I guess because you don't have values in cells A1, B1, C1, etc. You probably need to translate the starting point of the df to not be A1 but B7 in your case..

Comment: Any idea how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
df = pd.Dataframe(xl)
print(df.columns)
# if you can see the columns 
print(df["XX"])
# if this is success
dictionary = {"XX": list(df["XX"])}
```

Comment: I'm getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "excelToJson.py", line 8, in <module>
    df = pandas.Dataframe(xl)
  File "C:\Users\aironsid\Documents\Capgemini\Excel_to_Json\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 263, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Comment: ok got it try this `pd.read_excel('path', sheet_name="")`   and then convert to dataframe

Comment: Same problem. `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'`

Comment: ok i see you got the columns as (0,1, 2,3 ) in your comments try printing `df.head`  after editing your code so that you can see how the data is coming

Comment: I got a bunch of data in a table like format, all useful. This could be the way to use it and grab the data. Can I use it to select the specific data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217739/discussion-between-santhosh-reddy-and-alex-ironside).

Comment: This solves the problem of nulls, but I still get the same error, regarding keys. Isn't there a "grab C1:D5" solution for this? Or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you need to translate the starting point of A1 to B7 in your case.   This can be achieved with the "skiprows" parameter of `pandas.ExcelFile.parse` and the `index_col` parameter:

```
import pandas
xl = pandas.ExcelFile("path\to\your\file.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("YourSheetName",index_col=1,skiprows=7)
```

For more documentation/parameters see [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)

Comment: Ok this solves the problem of nulls, but I still get the same error, regarding keys. Isn't there a "grab C1:D5" solution for this?

Comment: you need to change the 1st row to column headers to avoid that error

Comment: @SanthoshReddy That is, increase skiprows by 1.